# How to warp flat svg image

Tags: animation, image, import

I need create simple cartoon like animation. I need import a svg image, and bend it. No movement only bending. For example a Christmas tree that bends in the wind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After importing a .SVG like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d1/Xmas_tree.svg) you see that it consists of many curves.

You can convert it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> Mesh from Curve...

After scaling and rotating all elements and relocating some parts you should have something like that:
[image]

Then it is up to you to:

- Animate the tree segments with glitter balls parented by simply keyframe their rotation.
- Join all to one mesh and add a shape keys to animate them (use proportional editing)
- Creating a rig is also possible but would be kinda overkill

Comment: When I Join all object is possible to 'unjoin' it ? <br/> Is possible to add a bones?

Comment: @Bardzo Yes you can separate them [P], which methods works best depends on your tree, the one I used has three tree segments so parenting works nice and I would only keyframe the three parent objects. If you insist to use bones simply add them and parent the objects to the bones.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Add your image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8532/2217) in to blender using the **Add Image as Plane** addon.
2. Add loop cuts to the image where you want it to bend. Read [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17888/2217) to see how to do so without stretching the texture.
3. Enable the [Anim All](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/AnimAll) addon
4. Using [proportional editing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit) and [keyframes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Actions) bend your image the way you want.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/user/Blender2DCom/videos) youtube channel has several videos about animation 2D drawings.

Comment: this youtube and web page is not good. meybe is a chance to produce good tutorial to all 2d animation toons? lige south park or paper cartoon?