# Correct UVs Blender 2.8x

Tags: uv, edges, distort, loop

I was wondering if there's the same feature as in Blender 2.7x, that if you check a  checkbox, your UV map get's stretched accordingly [like in this post.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17888/move-loopcut-without-distorting-uv-map)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) or edge slide (<kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) first

[image: Loop cut menu]

And then, there'll be some options. Then, check the Correct UVs

[image]

> After the modal tool is run the Loop Cut and Slide Options. These options are available in the Adjust Last Operation panel.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_slide.html